# What are the TBB changes required to enable GZip Compression in Tridion 2013 sp1?and also its Pros and Cons

Tags: 2013-sp1, dd4t-2, dd4t-java

My Spring config has `org.dd4t.providers.impl.BrokerComponentPresentationProvider` `contentIsCompressed` set to false.

I want to turn that to true to improve performance. But I am not sure what are the Template Building Block changes that need to be done in Tridon to enable it.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the DD4T 2.0 Templates (latest version 2.1.2), to enable compression I believe you have to add the `CompressOutput` TBB as last item in your Page Template. Not sure if you can also use it on a Component Template.

The benefits of using compression are that the size you push over the line (between the CM and Deployer) is less, and thus the transport takes less time. The downsides of using compression will be that you need additional processing power for compression and decompression. For certain scenarios the benefits will outweigh the downsides, I don't know of a list which tell you exactly for which scenarios these are.

Comment: Thanks Bart, 1)but how can we make changes to TBB? what changes we need to do, to support compression in tridion? 2)changes to DD4t alone be sufficient or we need to change the templates also?

Comment: Thank you so much Bart.But I need to know whether we can use CompressOutput TBB in Component Template because the component size is pretty much big and also If I use CompressOutput TBB will it corrupt the multibyte characters(Japanese etc.).Incase If I can use CompressOutput TBB Are there any numbers on compression rate, improvement in speed, how much processing power is needed. I know precise numbers are hard to come by, so even vague ones will do.

Comment: @user6814906 if the Component is used on a Page, then compression will be done as part of the Page, so in that case you don't need it on the Component Template. If the Component Template is a dynamic one, it is something you'll have to try, as mentioned I don't know the details of how smart it is. Further details I don't have, as I myself never used it, that info will have to come from the rest of the community.But you could simply try it out and see the results yourself, place the TBB, publish and measure, if its not as you want, remove the TBB and publish again.

Comment: @Brat I will try using CompressOutput TBB in Component Template for dynamic ones.[My only concern is I have many dynamic components which are more than 50 MB(Single Component)]. I will let you know my results after testing it.

Comment: @Vira if your Components are that large, I'm wondering if your link level isn't set too high, you have to be careful when setting it, and use it responsibly, since including everything 10 levels deep is most of the time just a waste of render time and bandwidth.

Comment: @Kiran505 you don't need changes to the TBBs, you need to include the `CompressOutput` TBB (which is part of the DD4T TBBs) in the modular Page Template. Once you have done that, every Page you publish will be compressed and the DD4T deserializer should automatically handle decompression i believe.

Comment: I can assure that the CompressOutput TBB of DD4T works with Component Template as well.

Comment: @Bart In DD4T 2, you don't need the Compress Output TBB. You can simply set the parameter 'Compress output' on the Generate Dynamic Page and the Generate Dynamic Component Presentation TBB. The Compress Output TBB is marked as obsolete, with the message "Enable compression by setting the template parameter CompressionEnabled to 'yes'". - I guess I should have spotted this 2 years ago :(